# Artifactory AQL post over ruby

Tags: ruby, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to query the Artifactory's AQL API using ruby code, I already checked that this code works on bash using curl:

`curl -u admin:password -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST http://server.example.com:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -T aql.aql`

Where aql.aql contents are as follows:

```
items.find
(
    {
        "repo":{"$eq":"test-ASO"}
    }
)
.include("name","property.*")
```

Now I'm trying to do the same using Ruby with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

payload ='items.find
(
    {
        "repo":{"$eq":"test-ASO"}
    }
).include("name","property.*")'

uri = URI.parse("http://server.example.com:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'password'
req.set_form_data(payload)
res = http.request(req)
puts res.body
```

But all that I get is:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Bad Request"
  } ]
}
```

My guess is that the payload of the query has to be a file, as I did before with curl (-T parameter) but I don't think that using files for queries is a very elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: Hey Alvaro, good question. Please formulate and accept an answer yourself, like that SO knows that this question is closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Finally I achieved this by declaring the req.body variable with the proper content:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

payload = 'items.find().include("name","property.*")'

uri = URI.parse("http://server.example.com:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"
req.basic_auth 'admin', 'password'
req.body = payload
res = http.request(req)
puts res.body
```